# Python: create arrays containing times and be able to sum them

Tags: python, timedelta

i need to create arrays containing time values (hh:mm:ss), sample a value from each array and sum them up.
I created the arrays using pd.timedelta_range() and sampled using rd.choices().
I would need to sum the sampled departure time and the duration to obtain an arrival time, but departure + duration just prints out the two values without delivering a total.

```
departure_time = pd.timedelta_range('04:00:00', '09:45:00', freq='15T')
departure_prob = (0.008, 0.008, 0.008,  0.008,  0.032,  0.032, 0.032,   0.032,  0.082,  0.082, 0.082,    
0.082,  0.08,   0.08, 0.08, 0.08,   0.034,  0.034,  0.034,  0.034,  0.014,  0.014, 0.014,   0.014)

duration_time = pd.timedelta_range('00:15:00', '01:15:00', freq='15T')
duration_prob = (0.355, 0.321, 0.152, 0.086, 0.086)

departure = rd.choices(departure_time, departure_prob)
duration = rd.choices(duration_time, duration_prob)
print(departure+duration)
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - `NameError: name 'rd' is not defined`

Comment: If `rd` is `random`, `departure` and `duration` are lists - you are concatenating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue you have is that the variables departure and duration are lists (each containing one element).
you need to extract the timedelta objects:
`departure[0]+duration[0]`

or more clearly:

```
departure = rd.choices(departure_time, departure_prob)[0]
duration = rd.choices(duration_time, duration_prob)[0]
```

then the `departure + duration` will work as you intend it to.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
import datetime

#departure_time = pd.timedelta_range('04:00:00', '09:45:00', freq='15T')
departure_time = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01 10:00', end='2017-01-02 09:00', freq='1h')
departure_prob = (0.008, 0.008, 0.008,  0.008,  0.032,  0.032, 0.032,   0.032,  0.082,  0.082, 0.082,    
0.082,  0.08,   0.08, 0.08, 0.08,   0.034,  0.034,  0.034,  0.034,  0.014,  0.014, 0.014,   0.014)

duration_time = pd.timedelta_range('00:15:00', '01:15:00', freq='15T')
duration_prob = (0.355, 0.321, 0.152, 0.086, 0.086)

departure = rd.choices(departure_time, departure_prob)
duration = rd.choices(duration_time, duration_prob)

print(departure[0]+duration[0])
```

If you want to get a time, you have to use a date. Timedelta is, as the name suggests, a timeperiod.

Comment: You probably want to change the _start_ and _end_ to match your use case, as well as _freq_